# image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform - Docker file for WCF project ASP.NET Framework 4.5.2

Tags: docker, wcf

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
RUN windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app 'Default Web Site/' /enabledProtocols:"http,net.tcp"
EXPOSE 808
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-bin/Debug/Publish} .
```

I am getting the error +++ image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform +++. I want to host the docker file in the Linux container.

Comment: I need to run the WCF API Project .NET Framework 4.5.2 on linux container!! is this possible?

Comment: You can take a look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c3e0b21-1ac7-4af3-9bf2-b1ba4b4dd857/is-wcf-fully-supported-on-linux?forum=wcf